# System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://127.0.0.1/TestService

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, tcp

I am hosting my Service :

```
  using (ServiceHost sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Class1)))
                {
                    sHost.Open();
                }

               // sHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service Started....");
                Console.ReadLine();
```

And trying to Use the service using channel factory:

```
  ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("");

            var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = proxy.DoProcessing();
```

I could see the service is started , with the endpoint , but when I try to create channel , getting following error.

> Test method TestService.Test.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://127.0.0.1/TestService. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0017385. TCP error code 10061: 
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808

This is my **Service configuration**:

```
    <services>
        <service name="Service1.ClassLibrary.Class1">
            <endpoint
              address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1/TestService"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="Service1.Interface.IService1" />

        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Client configuration:**

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1/TestService" binding="netTcpBinding"
                contract="Service1.Interface.IService1" />

</client>
```

Comment: The net library will not allow you to use connect() method with an ip address 127.0.0.1.  You have to use the computer IP address or name.  You can listen using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @jdweng, I tried with localhost , but same error

Comment: Some computers have localhost defined as 127.0.0.1 which will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
using (ServiceHost sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Class1)))
                {
                    sHost.Open();
                }
```

The `using bloick` auto-close the service  host and hence unavailable for clients.

Instead , this works perfect:

```
 ServiceHost sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Class1));
    sHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service Started....");
   //Keeps Servece Open
    Console.ReadLine();
 sHost.Close()
```